# iOS -- Using and Understanding Instruments using Allocations and Memory Monitor (Physical Memory Free)

Tags: ios, memory, instruments

I'm in the process of understanding how to put instruments to better use. I just finished a leak management exercise, and instruments is reporting very few leaks. I'll figure those out later. In the mean time, my app is crashing, and it appears that its related to memory pressure.

So I looked at this in Instruments. I have Allocations and Memory Monitor in use. Allocations shows a pretty steady 3 to 4 MB Live bytes while I just let my app initialize and come to equilibrium. Overall bytes, however, jumps to over 50 MB.  I didn't think much of this until I looked at the Memory Monitor and I see that memory usage goes up and down, causing memory warnings. (It seems strange to me that this doesn't show up on the allocations graph at the same time.)

The app should be at an equilibrium point, but apparently it's not. My question is how can I use instruments to help me understand why memory usages is rising and falling?

Comment: If your app is crashing, use the zombies tool, not the leaks tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instruments as a tool for debugging is simply excellent.  From what I can understand, you have been trying to use the allocations tool, so I'll go over that.  Allocations details the number of objects your application allocates during it's execution, along with their in-memory references, locations, even the calling code that allocates said objects.  When instruments starts running the allocations tool, your application begins reporting all allocations as blue dots, which pile up higher and higher as your application executes (naturally, as you should be allocating more and more objects).  Overall Bytes displays the amount of memory EVERY allocation your app has made added together.  I want to stress this for your case: **it does not mean your app is currently using 50 mb of memory!**, it just means that your app has used **50 mb total.**  Your app is obviously limited to the amount of memory the device has, and 3-4 mb is not a lot when you consider that the first gen. iPhone had about 128mb, but for more complicated applications, the OS will usually kill off other applications before it kills yours.

As for the other allocation graph with spikes, rather than a continuous line graph, that is to detail the number of allocations going on at that point in time.  Usually, the spikes can be ignored, unless there are a lot of large spikes in one small amount of time.

Anyways, to address your specific memory warning problem, it honestly depends how many memory warnings you are receiving, and at what level the warning are at.  And as for your leaks, my only word of advice is: Squash them as soon as possible!  When you see a leak (a red bar in the leaks tool), click on the bar and find the objects that are being leaked.  When you select a leaked object, then select the right sidebar, it will show you the code that is leaking.  When you double click on any part of the right sidebar, it'll even open up the specific line and class the leak originated from!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't see any blue dots in the allocations monitor. How do I set that up? I only see a solid-filled curve. I did find the Enable NSZombie detection in the launch configuration for Allocations. My launch configuration is Discard unrecorded, Style: current bytes, type:overlay. I'm not sure yet what these mean.

Comment: By 'Dots' (my apologies, that's what I always picture), I mean that the solid curve basically is full of those 'dots' (again, I'm sorry if I'm the only one who pictures the allocations feature like that).  To get the zombies tool running, I always just quit Instruments and then select the zombies template (that kind of greenish zombie-looking cube).